# Need help understanding proof relating to continuous functions from compact spaces

Tags: general-topology

In the following proof on page 174 of Munkres, I don't understand why the following statement is true:

If $A$ has no largest element, then the collection $\{(-\infty, a): a \in A\}$ forms an open covering of A.

Can someone please explain to me why it's true?

> $\textbf{Theorem:}$ Let $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ be continuous, where $Y$ is an ordered set in the order topology. If $X$ is compact, then there exist points $c$ and $d$ in $X$ such that $f(c) \leq f(x) \leq f(d)$ for every $x \in X$.
>
> $\textbf{Proof:}$ Since $f$ is continuous and X is compact, the set $A = f(X)$ is compact. We show that $A$ has a largest element $M$ and a smallest element $m$. Then since $m$ and $M$ belong to $A$, we must have $m = f(c)$ and $M=f(d)$ for some points $c$ and $d$ of $X$.
>
> If $A$ has no largest element, then the collection $\{(-\infty, a): a \in A\}$ forms an open covering of A. Since $A$ is compact, some finite subcollection $\{(-\infty, a_1), \ldots, (-\infty, a_n)\}$ covers $A$. If $a_i$ is the largest of the elements $a_1, \ldots, a_n$, then $a_i$ belongs to none of these sets, contrary to the fact that they cover $A$. A similar argument shows that $A$ has no smallest element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ has no largest element, for every $x\in A$ there is some $a\in A$ such that $x<a$ and therefore $x\in(-\infty,a)$. Therefore we have that $\bigcup_{a\in A}(-\infty,a)=A$.

Since the intervals $(-\infty,a)$ are open, this makes an open cover.

Comment: Ah. Now it makes sense. Thanks a bunch!